# Firebase cloud function does not trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to set up a pretty basic trigger functionality via Firebase. Whenever a document is added or updated in the Firestore, I want to trigger a function to create another document based on the data that was submitted in the initial document.

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
// Grab the text parameter.
const original = {
    days: {
        1: ["9:00-12:00","14:00-17:00"],
        2: ["9:00-12:00","14:00-16:00"],
        3: ["9:00-12:00","14:00-16:00"],
        4: ["9:00-12:00","14:00-16:00"],
        5: ["9:00-12:00","14:00-16:00"],
        6: ["9:00-12:00","14:00-16:00"],
        7: ["9:00-12:00","14:00-16:00"]
    }
}
// Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').doc("2023-1").set(original);
// Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
res.json({result: `Message with ID: 2023-1 added.`});
});
```

I've added this function for testing purposes right now and it works as expected. `addMessage` adds data to Firestore - messages collection is created with respective document and it's data.

I have another method which is supposed to run whenever a document is added to messages, however, it does not seem to trigger. I have exactly the same one added for the `onUpdate` functionality.

```
exports.createNewAvailabilityFromAdmin = functions.firestore.document('/messages/{documentId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to Firestore.
  const original = snap.data();

  // Access the parameter `{documentId}` with `context.params`
  functions.logger.log('Processing the new availability', context.params.documentId, original);
  let documentSplit = context.params.documentId.split("-");
  let currentYear = documentSplit[0];
  let currentMonth = documentSplit[1];
  // Fetch the bookings for current month
  // Generate availability based on bookings and the current context
  let availability = generateAvailabilityBasedOnDates(null,original.days,currentMonth,currentYear);
  // Store availability
  functions.logger.log(availability);
  return admin.firestore().doc('publicAvailability/'+context.params.documentId).set(availability);
});
```

I don't think the contents of `createNewAvailabilityFromAdmin` require any type of explanation as if there would be any issues with triggering this, i'd see errors in the emulator. The problem is that I don't get any feedback that this method was started in the first place.

In the console from the emulator I see following:

[image]

But the method `createNewAvailabilityFromAdmin` does not seem to trigger and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the issue was within the fact that emulator did not have 'firestore' enabled (and the function was storing the data directly into actual firestore and not into the emulated firestor). When I enabled the emulator firestore, it started throwing errors about cloud functions.